# Apply scale factors to MODIS NDVI in the code to make time series of inter annual average in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, modis

I'm new to GEE. I'm working on NDVI time series. I want to know how to multiply all the images inside  a ImageCollection by scale factor 0.0001 to get real NDVI values to  make chat of inter annual average. How to apply scale factor in this code?

```
[![// Define a point to extract an NDVI time series for.
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point(\[88.44660053263999,26.756420226194336\]);

// function scale 

// var scale = function(image){
//   return image.multiply(0.0001);
// };

// Define a band of interest (NDVI), import the MODIS vegetation index dataset,
// and select the band.
var band = 'NDVI';
var ndviCol = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').select(band);
//.map(scale);

// Map over the collection to add a day of year (doy) property to each image.
ndviCol = ndviCol.map(function(img) {
  var doy = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).getRelative('day', 'year');
  // Add 8 to day of year number so that the doy label represents the middle of
  // the 16-day MODIS NDVI composite.
  return img.set('doy', ee.Number(doy).add(8));
});

// Join all coincident day of year observations into a set of image collections.
var distinctDOY = ndviCol.filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01');
var filter = ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'doy', rightField: 'doy'});
var join = ee.Join.saveAll('doy_matches');
var joinCol = ee.ImageCollection(join.apply(distinctDOY, ndviCol, filter));

// Calculate the absolute range, interquartile range, and median for the set
// of images composing each coincident doy observation group. The result is
// an image collection with an image representative per unique doy observation
// with bands that describe the 0, 25, 50, 75, 100 percentiles for the set of
// coincident doy images.
var comp = ee.ImageCollection(joinCol.map(function(img) {
  var doyCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(img.get('doy_matches'));

  return doyCol
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile(
          \[0, 25, 50, 75, 100\], \['p0', 'p25', 'p50', 'p75', 'p100'\]))
      .set({'doy': img.get('doy')});
}));

// Extract the inter-annual NDVI doy percentile statistics for the
// point of interest per unique doy representative. The result is
// is a feature collection where each feature is a doy representative that
// contains a property (row) describing the respective inter-annual NDVI
// variance, formatted as a list of values.
var reductionTable = comp.map(function(img) {
  var stats = ee.Dictionary(img.reduceRegion(
      {reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), geometry: geometry, scale: 250}));

  // Order the percentile reduction elements according to how you want columns
  // in the DataTable arranged (x-axis values need to be first).
  var row = ee.List(\[
    img.get('doy'),            // x-axis, day of year.
    stats.get(band + '_p50'),  // y-axis, median.
    stats.get(band + '_p0'),   // y-axis, min interval.
    stats.get(band + '_p25'),  // y-axis, 1st quartile interval.
    stats.get(band + '_p75'),  // y-axis, 3rd quartile interval.
    stats.get(band + '_p100')  // y-axis, max interval.
  \]);

  // Return the row as a property of an ee.Feature.
  return ee.Feature(null, {row: row});
});

// Aggregate the 'row' properties to make a server-side 2-D array (DataTable).
var dataTableServer = reductionTable.aggregate_array('row');

// Define column names and properties for the DataTable. The order should
// correspond to the order in the construction of the 'row' property above.
var columnHeader = ee.List(\[\[
  {label: 'Day of year', role: 'domain'},
  {label: 'Median', role: 'data'},
  {label: 'p0', role: 'interval'},
  {label: 'p25', role: 'interval'},
  {label: 'p75', role: 'interval'},
  {label: 'p100', role: 'interval'}
\]\]);

// Concatenate the column header to the table.
dataTableServer = columnHeader.cat(dataTableServer);

// Use 'evaluate' to transfer the server-side table to the client, define the
// chart and print it to the console.
dataTableServer.evaluate(function(dataTableClient) {
  var chart = ui.Chart(dataTableClient).setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
    title: 'Annual NDVI Time Series with Inter-Annual Variance',
    intervals: {style: 'area'},
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Day of year',
      titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true},
    },
    vAxis: {title: 'NDVI (x1e4)', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
    colors: \['0f8755'\],
    legend: {position: 'none'}
  });
  print(chart);
});
```

[enter link description here](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/f3f61df54a5957de92ffc7d5714bc22b)

Comment: Could you check the link or add the code as text in your question?

Comment: Code (or the relevant chunk thereof) should always be in the Question, even if the link is/was functional.